# What's wrong with here? Python2 ->Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I'm practicing Python with the book called Learn "Python The Hard Way 3rd edition". I searched that this book is a good resource to get a start.

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print('The script is called: '+ script)
print ('Your first variable is: '+ first)
print ('Your second variable is: '+ second)
print ('Your third variable is: '+ third)
```

And I got an error saying that `value error: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the script with three arguments, so that `argv` contains four elements (the first is the script's name).

Comment: can you give more examples on this?

Comment: @OliverBird sure: `$ python myscript.py one two three`

Comment: Thanks. I got my results!

Answer (score 1):

argv is a list containing the following:
argv[0] is the script pathname if known
argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]... contains arguments passed from the shell.

In order for your code to work you need to run it with 3 arguments so that they can be unpacked and assigned to your 4 variables.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful as well!